# Split time by hr and min

Tags: php

I have a db table that contains time in the following format hhmm.

I need to split hour from minutes. I think I can use something like

```
substr($time, 0, 2);
```

It works well when my time looks like: `1430`, however I'm not sure what to do when I have something like `710`.

Comment: Use a negative offset instead. `substr($time, 0, -2);`

Comment: there should be a way to "take [right,left]-most ~n~ characters".  So right(2) and left(length - 2)

Comment: I would say `710` is not in hhmm format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative offset instead, that counts backwards from the end of the string

```
substr($time, 0, -2);
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php